# Chrome Extension for Console - select frame

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a Chrome extension to help debugging. I can't see any API for editing the console panel. What I mainly want to do is to automatically select the frame to a given one. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: This is what's available: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools